# Generic Pool "More Items Recycled than obtained" issue

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using a Generic Pool to add sprites to a Scene in AndEngine with an interval of every 1 second.

As the sprites are added i recycle them as they collide with certain objects.

I keep getting this error

```
12-27 12:45:07.890: E/AndEngine(25299): More items recycled than obtained!
12-27 12:45:07.890: E/AndEngine(25299): java.lang.Exception
12-27 12:45:07.890: E/AndEngine(25299):     at org.anddev.andengine.util.Debug.e(Debug.java:117)
12-27 12:45:07.890: E/AndEngine(25299):     at org.anddev.andengine.util.Debug.e(Debug.java:107)
12-27 12:45:07.890: E/AndEngine(25299):     at org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.GenericPool.recyclePoolItem(GenericPool.java:127)
12-27 12:45:07.890: E/AndEngine(25299):     at com.fttech.hungryhippos.Arcade_MainGame$1.onUpdate(Arcade_MainGame.java:738)
```

It isnt causing a Force close but i do worry that it can cause issues later on.

Is the an error that i should be worried about?

Also here is how i recycle my items..

```
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.setVisible(false);
    pItem.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From herpderp on AndEngine forums:

> It means what it says. In the GenericPool source there's a member
>   variable that increments when obtainPoolItem is called, and decrements
>   when recyclePoolItem is called. If it falls below zero - in other
>   words, if recyclePoolItem is called more times than obtainPoolItem is
>   called - then you get that error message.
>
> There's no simple fix for this problem. You just have to look over
>   your code, specifically at where you recycle and obtain pool items,
>   and try to figure out why recyclePoolItem would be called too often.